# header and source files in jni

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an Android project in Eclipse. In the `jni` folder I create `Store.h` where I just define:

```
class Store{
};
```

And in `Store.c` I type:

```
#include "Store.h"
```

And I get error in the definition of `class Store` but if I use `Store.hpp` and `Store.cpp` files instead of `.h` and `.c` I don't get any errors. Could anyone explain why? Which format is better to use in this case and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.cpp` for C++ files, and `.c` for C files. `.h` and `.hpp` are both fine for any C++ header files - but `.h` is more common.

The reason your code is not compiling when the file has a `.c` extension, is because a C compiler is being used based on the file extension. When you rename it to have a `.cpp` extension, a C++ compiler is used and the code compiles fine.